# odd integers that are divisible by a perfect cube

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove :

There exist 7 consecutive odd integers that are each divisible by a perfect cube greater than 1.

it is exist statement so if it is true we have to provide example and if it is false then we have to prove it

I see it is false statement because I do not find sequence like 7 consecutive odd integers that are each divisible by a perfect cube greater than 1.

let the 7 consecutive odd integers look like $2k+1 , 2k+3 , 2k+5,2k+7 ,2k+9 , 2k+11 $, and $2k+13$ are odd so if we select any positive integer $k$ there is at least one of odd integer will be prime

so , we cannot have cubic divisor

is my work correct or any suggestion on that?
thanks

Comment: Have you heard of the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: There is no reason why one of seven consecutive odd integers should be prime, so no, your work is not correct.

Comment: @Dylan If the penny doesn't drop soon, you might as well post that as an answer. It is easy to foresee that otherwise somebody else will :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , what would be wrong with that?

Comment: @Malcolm , what is the correct way that I can use ? thank you

Comment: "so if we select any positive integer k there is at least one of odd integer will be prime "  Why on earth would that follow?  consider $k = 13! +1= 13*12*11*....*3*2*1+1$.  None of $2k + 1$ (which is divisible by $3$ to $2k + 13$ (which is divisible by $15$) are prime.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Not much really. The way I read it was that Dylan was trying to induce the OP to see the light. At least I often try something similar myself. Sometimes it works, but it's relatively rare :-) Either nothing happens, or somebody else posts an answer. My prediction was that this is an interesting enough question so that someone is bound to get excited enough about their solution not to wait. This is not necessarily a bad thing at all. On a question with less context OTOH.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I can't see how answering a question with less context is bad, despite the site culture to the contrary. I just gathered from your emoji that you saw a problem: "Somebody else will :-/"

Comment: @GTonyJacobs There was some of that, granted. But, I'm not very accurate with emojis :-) Re: more/less context. I seek to be flexible myself. IMO an interesting question (like this) needs less context, but not everybody agrees. And I do see the problem with "my interesting" $\neq$ "your interesting" $\neq$ "everybody's interesting". My comment was also meant to be kinda warning to Dylan - the attempt to make the asker work on the hint may fail, and he may not be able to pick the fruit later. And, to make sure, making a comment does not come with any kind of a monopoly to the expressed idea.

Comment: Yeah, that "pick up the fruit" part..... Are we assuming that anyone making a comment is looking for a reward? There is no "fruit" to pick up. Are you talking about reputation? Why presume that anyone commenting is concerned with that?

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to prove this for $3$ consecutive odd integers, rather than $7,$ I would pick $3$ primes, say $5$, $7$, and $11$.  Then I would use Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve the system

$$2n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{ 5^3}$$
$$2n+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{7^3}$$
$$2n+5 \equiv 0 \pmod{11^3}$$

to get $n = 17242437$.  The first of the $3$ integers is $34484875.$

Comment: Thank you very much, Do you have another way to solve it with out using Chinese Remainder Theorem ?

Comment: Not really.  You can avoid CRT, but you'll have to do essentially the same calculations.

Comment: $$2n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{ 3^7}$$
$$2n+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{5^7}$$
$$2n+5 \equiv 0 \pmod{7^7}$$                                                              $$2n+7 \equiv 0 \pmod{ 9^7}$$
$$2n+9 \equiv 0 \pmod{11^7}$$
$$2n+11 \equiv 0 \pmod{13^7}$$            $$2n+13 \equiv 0 \pmod{1^7}$$   so it will be look like that and after that I have to find n

Comment: Not quite.  The moduli should be cubed.  Also $9$ is not prime.  Also the last modules should be $17^3$.

Comment: $$2n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{ 5^3}$$
$$2n+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{7^3}$$
$$2n+5 \equiv 0 \pmod{3^3}$$                                                         $$2n+7 \equiv 0 \pmod{ 5^3}$$
$$2n+11 \equiv 0 \pmod{17^3}$$
$$2n+13 \equiv 0 \pmod{13^3}$$

Comment: is that correct please help me with the correct answer?

Comment: That system will give you a correct answer.  The number will be very large.  Good luck.

Comment: Actually, you need a 7th congruence, so add $2n+9 \equiv 0\pmod{19^3}.$